# How can I get multiple values at once from my websocket

Tags: javascript, html

Whenever I use `document.getElementById` it works but only one value and the other values on the page show as undefined as expected. And when I use `document.querySelectorAll`. I get nothing, I know I am doing something wrong. Any help is much appreciated.

Here is the part of the code that works with `document.getElementById`.

**Snippet**

```html
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Simple Live Display</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var ws;
        var wsUri = "ws:";
        var loc = window.location;
        console.log(loc);
        if (loc.protocol === "https:") { wsUri = "wss:"; }
        // This needs to point to the web socket in the Node-RED flow
        // ... in this case it's ws/simple
        wsUri += "//" + loc.host + loc.pathname.replace("simple","ws/simple");

        function wsConnect() {
            console.log("connect",wsUri);
            ws = new WebSocket(wsUri);
              // either uncomment this for a building list of messages
            ws.onmessage = function(msg) {
                var line = "";  // or uncomment this to overwrite the existing message
                // parse the incoming message as a JSON object
                var data = JSON.parse(msg.data);
                //console.log(data);
                // build the output from the topic and payload parts of the object
                line += "<p><b>SAT</b> "+data.SAT+"</p>";
                line += "<p><b>OAT</b> "+data.OAT+"</p>";
                line += "<p><b>OAH</b> "+data.OAH+"</p>";
                line += "<p><b>SAT</b> "+data.SAT+"</p>";
                line += "<p><b>RAT</b> "+data.RAT+"</p>";
                line += "<p><b>Space T</b> "+data.Space_T+"</p>";
                line += "<p><b>Space H</b> "+data.Space_H+"</p>";
                line += "<p><b>Attic T</b> "+data.Attic_T+"</p>";
                line += "<p><b>Gas</b> "+data.Gas+"</p>";
                line += "<p><b>Compressor</b> "+data.Compressor+"</p>";
                line += "<p><b>Heat Stage1</b> "+data.Heat_Stage_1+"</p>";
                line += "<p><b>Attic T SP</b> "+data.Attic_T_SP+"</p>";
                line += "<p><b>Space T SP</b> "+data.Space_T_SP+"</p>";
                line += "<p><b>Evap Fan</b> "+data.Evap_Fan+"</p>";
                line += "<p><b>Attic Fan</b> "+data.Attic_Fan+"</p>";
                // replace the messages div with the new "line"
                document.getElementById('SAT').innerHTML = "Supply Air Temp &nbsp = &nbsp"+data.SAT;
                document.getElementById('OAT').innerHTML = "Outside Air Temp &nbsp = &nbsp"+data.OAT;
                document.getElementById('OAH').innerHTML = "Outside Air Humidity &nbsp = &nbsp"+ data.OAH;
                document.getElementById('RAT').innerHTML = "Return Air Temp &nbsp = &nbsp"+ data.RAT;
                document.getElementById('Space T').innerHTML = "Space Temp &nbsp = &nbsp"+ data.Space_T;
                document.getElementById('Space H').innerHTML = "Space Humidity &nbsp = &nbsp"+ data.Space_H;
                document.getElementById('Attic T').innerHTML = "Attic Temp &nbsp = &nbsp"+ data.Attic_T;
                document.getElementById('Gas').innerHTML = "Gas Heat &nbsp = &nbsp"+ data.Gas;
                document.getElementById('Compressor').innerHTML = "Compressor &nbsp = &nbsp"+ data.Compressor;
                document.getElementById('Heat Stage1').innerHTML = "Reversing Valve &nbsp = &nbsp"+ data.Heat_Stage_1;
                document.getElementById('Attic T SP').innerHTML = "Attic Temp SP &nbsp = &nbsp"+ data.Attic_T_SP;
                document.getElementById('Space T SP').innerHTML = "Space Temp SP &nbsp = &nbsp"+ data.Space_T_SP;
                document.getElementById('Evap Fan').innerHTML = "Evap Fan &nbsp = &nbsp"+ data.Evap_Fan;
                document.getElementById('Attic Fan').innerHTML = "Attic Fan &nbsp = &nbsp"+ data.Attic_Fan;
   
            }
            ws.onopen = function() {
                // update the status div with the connection status
                document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "connected";
                //ws.send("Open for data");
                console.log("connected");
            }
            ws.onclose = function() {
                // update the status div with the connection status
                document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "not connected";
                // in case of lost connection tries to reconnect every 3 secs
                setTimeout(wsConnect,3000);
            }
        }
    </script>

    </head>
    <body onload="wsConnect();" onunload="ws.disconnect();">
        <font face="Arial">
        <h1>Simple Live Display</h1>
        <div id="OAT">Outside Air Temp</div>
        <div id="OAH">Outside Air Humidity</div>
        <div id="SAT">Supply Air Temp</div>
        <div id="RAT">Return Air Temp</div>
        <div id="Space T">Space Temp</div>
        <div id="Space H">Space Humidity</div>
        <div id="Attic T">Attic Temp</div>
        <div id="Gas">Gas Heat</div>
        <div id="Compressor">Compressor</div>
        <div id="Heat Stage1">Reversing Valve</div>
        <div id="Attic T SP">Attic Temp SP</div>
        <div id="Space T SP">Space Temp SP</div>
        <div id="Evap Fan">Evap Fan</div>
        <div id="Attic Fan">Attic Fan</div>
        <div id="status">unknown</div>
        </font>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: IDs must be unique to the document, so there should only be one element with a given ID in a document. Also IDs should not have spaces in them (if they do, they must be escaped in the query). `querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList`, which doesn't have an `innerHTML` property.

Comment: It should be noted too that you build up a bunch of HTML in the `line` variable, but do nothing with the result....

Comment: This code is klind of all over the place. Don't use .innerHTML when you want to set text, use .textConten, and don't compose HTML as string, just use DOM functions (createEelement, append, etc). By most importantly for the core question: your `id` attribtues have illegal values. There are strict rules on what an `id` can look like, and it [cannot contain whitespace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id).